# How do I remove a user from TFS 2018?

Tags: security, tfs

I have a user that is getting alerts from TFS.  When I looked at [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_Identity] I found several people that I have no idea how they got in there.

When I do a backup of the TFS server through the console, they get an email notification.

How do I remove them?  I have tried attempting to sync with JobService, rebooted the server, looked in AD at the person, and I've looked in TFS in User Management in the Console.  They are not there.  I can find them in TFS if I search for a Subscriber on a Project, but nothing in regards to backup or the like or a way to remove them from the entire TFS instance.

I have also looked a the Console and group membership for individual projects.  They are not Team Foundation Administrators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not: TFS/VSTS/ADO needs to refer to past users reference in work item, version control and other subsystems.

You can break your database in an unrecoverable way modifying the `tbl_Identity` table.

The only reasonable thing to do is to remove these users from all TFS (and Active Directory) groups so they only appears in old data. The [`TFSSecurity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/ref/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd#identities-and-membership) utility can help you identify which groups has a specific user.

Comment: Using tfssecurity doesn't show the user as part of any collection.  Other users do show up.